# Create columns in DOJO border container

Tags: css, dojo

I want to use DOJO border container in my page. I have this sample.

```
    <script>
      require(["dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane","dojo/domReady!"], 
      function(BorderContainer, ContentPane){
      // create a BorderContainer as the top widget in the hierarchy
       var bc = new BorderContainer({
        style: "height: 300px; width: 500px;"
      });

// create a ContentPane as the center pane in the BorderContainer
var cp2 = new ContentPane({
    region: "center",
    content: "how are you?,this is a test content"
});
bc.addChild(cp2);

// put the top level widget into the document, and then call startup()
bc.placeAt(document.body);
bc.startup();
});
</script>
```

I want to create some columns so that it looks like a table. How can I do that??
Can someone help me

Comment: BorderContainer doesn't function that way. See the examples. What exactly do you understand by looking like a table?

Comment: I want 2-3 columns and 10 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your title, "create columns **in** Dojo BorderContainer" (emphasis mine), then I would think a [dgrid](http://www.dgrid.io/), [table container](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/layout/TableContainer.html), or [grid container](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/layout/GridContainer.html) inside the border container would suit, depending upon what you were trying to accomplish with the table.

If the table is for data, consider dgrid.  If the table is for form layout, consider table container.  If the table is for widget layout, consider a grid container.

Here's an example using grid container.  nbZones is the number of columns.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <link href='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojox/widget/Portlet/Portlet.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <link href='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojox/layout/resources/GridContainer.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js'></script>
        <style type='text/css'>
        html,body,#border { margin:0; width:100%; height:100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class='claro'>
        <div id='border' data-dojo-type='dijit/layout/BorderContainer'>
            <div id='grid'></div>
        </div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        require(
            ['dojo/ready', 'dojo/parser', 'dojox/layout/GridContainer', 'dojox/widget/Portlet'],
            function (ready, Parser, GridContainer, Portlet) {
                ready(function () {
                    Parser.parse().then(function () {
                        // create grid and put into border container
                        var grid = new GridContainer({nbZones:3}, 'grid');

                        // create cells and put into grid
                        for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                            grid.addChild(new Portlet({
                                closable:false,
                                content:'(' + Math.floor(i/3) + ', ' + (i%3) + ')'
                            }));
                        }
                        grid.startup();
                    });
                });
            }
        );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```